# Install ArcGIS apps on my iPhone. Is there a manual or instructions for it?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-mobile

I have installed ArcGIS ESRI on my iPhone. Is there a manual or steps on how to use it? I want to know how to use it.

Comment: Are you referring to the ArcGIS Online app that is available from the App Store or are you trying to install ArcGIS (the software suite) on your iPhone?  The app is very easy to install, just download it and enter your username and password for arcGIS online.  I am not aware of any way to install something like the ArcGIS software suite onto an iOS device.

Comment: No I installed it from the ITunes. Is that suppose to work with the ArcGIS online ?

Comment: The arcGIS app from iTunes links to your ArcGIS online account and can be used with maps that you have built and published from arcGIS desktop.  Check out http://resources.arcgis.com/en/tutorials/ for some good tutorials that should get you started.

Comment: @KevinV, you should enter your 2 comments as an "answer" so PROBERT can accept it as the correct answer (which it is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to the ArcGIS Online app that is available from the App Store or are you trying to install ArcGIS (the software suite) on your iPhone? The app is very easy to install, just download it and enter your username and password for arcGIS online. I am not aware of any way to install something like the ArcGIS software suite onto an iOS device.

The arcGIS app from iTunes links to your ArcGIS online account and can be used with maps that you have built and published from arcGIS desktop. Check out [resources.arcgis.com/en/tutorials](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/tutorials) for some good tutorials that should get you started.